# Is the this the correct way of using OOP for a student class?

Tags: php, object-oriented

I tried use use HTML tags as my own way in PHP using objects.

Is this the correct method of writing or implementing OOP?  If not, what is the best way to write such type of code?

```
 <?php
    class HTMLCoding {
    private $classname;
    private $classstyle;
    function applyStyle($classname,$classstyle){
    $this->classname = $classname;
    $this->classstyle = $classstyle;
    ECHO <<<_END
    <style>
    .$this->classname { $this->classstyle }
    </style>
    _END;
    }
     private $class;
     function startTable($class){
     $this->class = $class;
    ECHO <<<_END
     <table class="$this->class">
    _END;
     }
     function endTable(){
    ECHO <<<_END
     </table>
    _END;
     }
      function startRow(){
    ECHO <<<_END
     <tr>
    _END;
     }
      function endRow(){
    ECHO <<<_END
     </tr>
    _END;
     }
     private $text;
      function makeColumn($class,$text){
      $this->text = $text;
      $this->class = $class;
    ECHO <<<_END
     <td class="$this->class">
     $this->text
     </td>
    _END;
     }

     };
    $variable = "My Name is Zafar Lehri";
    $obj = new HTMLcoding();

    $obj->startTable("zafar");
    $obj->startRow();
    $obj->makeColumn("studentname",$variable);
    $obj->makeColumn("studentname",$variable);
    $obj->makeColumn("studentname",$variable);
    $obj->makeColumn("studentname",$variable);
    $obj->endRow();
    $obj->endTable();
    $obj->applyStyle("zafar","width:800px; border:1px solid #000; border-radius:5px; margin:0 auto;");
    $obj->applyStyle("studentname","width:150px; border:1px solid #ccc; border-radius:15px;");

    ?>
```

Comment: Don't re-invent the wheel, that's the whole point of OOP. If you are going to use objects to churn out a DOM, [take a look at what's already out there](http://www.php.net/DOMDocument).

Answer (score 3):

First off, I suggest you separate the logic from the presentation. That means deal with the HTML later, do the structure of the code first. Then before I forget, I recommend you improve your indentation.

OOP is "Object Oriented Programming". In simple terms, you treat your code like real objects, that can be described, and that can do stuff. The very first thing you do in OOP is to find out the objects needed. In your case, you have a table of students - **table** and **student**. Next you find out how to describe them, and what they can do. In your case:

**Student**

- Has a name

**StudentList**

- Has a list of **Student** s
- Can add **Student** s

Therefore, you can them model the API to do like so (pardon my PHP, it's been a while):

```
public class Student {

  // Stores the student name
  public $name;

  public function __construct($name){
    // Initialize name
    $this->name = $name;
  }

}

public class StudentList {

  public $students;

  public function __construct(){
    // Initialize array
    $this->students = array();
  }

  // Add a student
  public function addStudent($student){
    array_push($this->students,$student);
  }

  public function display(){
    // loop through $this->students and echo HTML
    // or better, use a template library
  }

}

// Sample usage

$alice = new Student('Alice');
$bob = new Student('Bob');

$studentList = new StudentList();
$studentList->addStudent($alice);
$studentList->addStudent($bob);
```

As for displaying, I'd encourage you to use a templating library rather than doing some manual `echo`ing. Checkout [Mustache](https://github.com/bobthecow/mustache.php), it's very simple. That way, you won't be tempted to do `echo` or mix in HTML with the logic. Cut bad practices while early.

Comment: Your class should also be encapsulated, basically make all your internal arguments private and expose them using methods (e.g. name() and setName() if you need to be able to change a name)

Comment: @Pinoniq I intentionally left them public to keep it simple, and to have the OP figure it out. :D